# Microsoft office Macro - Why is the document jumping around?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

This if the first time I write a Microsoft Office Macro.

Basically, we have a few check boxes on page 1 and when one of them is checked, I need to auto-fill a text box on page 10 depending on which check box was checked. So each checkbox "on Entry" runs a macro.

Say the options are  "Outstanding", "Exceeded" and "Unsatisfactory". When "Outstanding" is checked, that text box will be filled with "O",  when "Exceeded" is checked, the text box will be filled with "E"

So the issue right now is, whenever I check the check box on page 1, suddenly, the document will jump to Page 10.

All I did was doing something like

```
oFFld("Text23").Result = "O"
```

I need it to stay on the same page! If I got rid of the above code, setting a value to the textbox, then nothing happens and I will stay on page 1.

What's going on? Any advice is greatly appreciated it.

ps:

it's word 2007

Comment: check that the macro did not create a statement for the worksheet (page 10) selection.

Comment: @almog, hm. I'm pretty new at this. What statement for the worksheet? 

All I did in the macro is a simple If Else statement and set the .Result = "whatever"

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.

I was using an evaluation expression as in

If OFFld("Text23").Result = "blah" Then

whenever I do that, it'll jump to the page 10. Took care of it in another way. solved.

Answer (score 0):

See answer in [Suppress unwanted jumping/scrolling on Word 2013 VBA Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889709/suppress-unwanted-jumping-scrolling-on-word-2013-vba-macro) for details, but essentially you want to use the `Bookmark` object rather than the `FormField` object to access the result property.