# Suppress unwanted jumping/scrolling on Word 2013 VBA Script

Tags: vba, ms-word

When accessing Legacy Form Field values in my Word 2013 document like this (getting or setting):

```
' get
myField = ActiveDocument.FormFields("myField").Result

' set
ActiveDocument.FormFields("myField").Result = myValue
```

the document weirdly jumps/scrolls down and up and stops at a complete different position (it seems to jump to the lines where the referred fields are positioned).

Have a look at [this screencast](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/859390/weird-scrolling.mp4) or [a sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jurrkfdxpslnrwi/sanitized.docm?dl=0) where the error can be viewed.

I have used

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

at the beginning of my `Sub` and

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

at the end of my `Sub` but unfortunately this doesn't help.

What do I have to modify in order to suppress this behaviour?

Comment: Sounds like you are on the right track... Can you provide a sample file I can use to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: I added [a sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jurrkfdxpslnrwi/sanitized.docm?dl=0) to the question.

Comment: Well thank you for spending time on my problem!

Comment: Aha! Found a workaround! Will be posting the answer shortly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a clue to the solution on the [Word MVP Site](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/tblsfldsfms/GotoFormField.htm). Like you pointed out, the issue is when you access the properties of a `FormField` object, the focus is set to this form field. You can see this behavior even when browsing the form fields through the Locals Window in the VBA editor.

Instead of using the `FormField` object, access the `Result` property through the `Bookmark` object.

*Change this:*

```
myField = ActiveDocument.FormFields("myField").Result
```

*To this:*

```
myField = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("myField").Range.Fields(1).Result
```

Now you can access the value of this field without changing the focus in your document. To set a value on a field, you can use the `Text` property.

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("myField").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = myValue
```

Hope this helps!! :-)

Comment: Ymmd, I've been facing and worrying about this issue for days. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can get/set the value of a checkbox? Your answer only works for text fields. (I've posed a [new question for this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903616/how-to-properly-access-legacy-form-field-checkboxes-in-word-2013-vba)).

Answer (score 1):

This is a fantastic workaround if all you need to access is the Result field. Unfortunately, some of the form field properties are not accessible indirectly through the Bookmark collection, most notably StatusText. I am using formfields to build tests that are graded automatically in VBA code, and StatusText is the only field (to my knowledge) that allows you to store static (non-volatile) answer data in each form field.

Here's a sample of the code I am using. The following loop tests the Result fields to see if they match the answers stored in the StatusText field

```
For Each fld In oFormFields

    strResult = fld.Result
    strStatus = fld.StatusText

    If strStatus = strResult Then
        ' color answer green to show that it was correct
        fld.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
     Else
        ' color answer red to show that it was wrong
        fld.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
     End If
 Next fld
```

I see no way of replacing the form field references with bookmark references, but perhaps I am missing something.